# Error message in Kaggle when reading in csv file

Tags: python, csv, types, kaggle, user-defined-data-types

```
data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/covidtracking/all-states-history.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
data.shape
```

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3063: 
DtypeWarning: Columns (2) have mixed types.
Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
(16931, 41)
```

Column (2) has quality rating elements with values such as A, A+, B, B+ etc

In the CSV file the data type listed above each column is "standard".

Comment: it seems it has problem to recognize type of data (string, float, int, etc) and you may have to manually set it in `read_csv` or you can use `low_memory=False` in `read_csv` so it would use more memory to load all data and check type of data in all rows.

Answer (score 0):

It means your CSV file has a column that consists of several different dtypes.
Just add `low_memory=False` to your `read_csv` function, and the warning message would be gone.

```
data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/covidtracking/all-states-history.csv', low_memory=False, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

But the problem is still there!

A better solution is to specify the column type. For example in your case, Columns (2):

```
data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/covidtracking/all-states-history.csv', dtype={2: str}, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```